# Nested jquery with lot of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to generate my html using jquery with json data, but its nested.

So I have json data:

```
{
  "A" : ['a1','b1','c1'],
  "B" : ['a2','b2','c2'],
  "C" : ['a3','b3','c3']
}
```

and I want append to my html like this :

```
<select option="A">
    <optgroup label ="A">
        <option>a1</option>
        <option>b1</option>
        <option>c1</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label ="B">
        <option>a2</option>
        <option>b2</option>
        <option>c2</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

can I use jquery.each for this? and is it good for my web performance? or is there any better methods I can use?

And the extra problem is, the data is overflow, but I can filter it because I only need some of the array, not all.

`var shownData = ['A', 'C']`: this mean I only want to show 2 optgroup, A and C

I have tried using nested jquery but its undefined, maybe because it is string(?), like this:

```
var arr = ['A'];
$.JSON("JSON.json", function(data){
 $.each(arr, function(index, value){
   $.each(data.value,function(i,val){
    console.log(val);
   });
 });
})
```

oh.. using it as array.. solve it :D

```
var arr = ['A'];
$.JSON("JSON.json", function(data){
 $.each(arr, function(index, value){
   $.each(data[value],function(i,val){
    console.log(val);
   });
 });
})
```

so is there any better method?..

Comment: You can always use native `array.forEach` or a simple `for` for better performance. Of course it is a micro optmization and would be *visible* only with a big collection of data.

Comment: It is `undefined` because `data.value === data['value']` while `data.valueOfValue === data[value]`

Comment: `data.value` makes no sense inside outer `$.each`. You have to use `value` instead of `data.value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `data[value]` instead of `data.value` : http://jsfiddle.net/u4sd5h1y/3/

You can access properties of an object by using `myObject.myProperty` or `myObject["myProperty"]`. Use the "." when the name of the property is known in code. Use the "[]" method when the name of the property is stored in a variable.

Comment: Thank you for your response, actually I ady edit it XD, so is there any better method than using jquery.each?

Comment: As previously said, you will have better performance by using a `for` loop. If you modify the DOM in your loop (by adding select components), don't forget to hide the modified part before treatment and display it only after the treatment. Otherwise the browser will recompute the DOM each time you modify it.

Answer (score 1):

`$.each()` is basically a `for (name in object)` with a callback, but `forEach` is to my knowledge generally faster than a for-loop. The below is probably the second fastest way to do it :

```
var optGroup, 
    option, 
    select = document.getElementById('select');

for (og in obj) {
    optGroup = document.createElement('optgroup');
    optGroup.setAttribute('label', og);
    select.appendChild(optGroup);
    obj[og].forEach(function(opt) {
        option = document.createElement('option');
        option.textContent = opt;
        optGroup.appendChild(option);
    })     
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/d7zys0z1/**

The fastest way is to built it up in a [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) you inject to the DOM afterwards.